# Same User, multiple Accounts

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I developed a simple Symfony2 application where exists organizations and users. An User has an organization, something like:

```
class Organization{
    private $id;
    private $name;
}

class User{
    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $organizationId;
    private $isActive;
    private $roles;
    private $level;
}
```

Now the requisites changed and an User can belong to many organizations, but the access data remains, witch means that the email and the password are still assigned to the User, but the other values like isActive, roles, and level are company dependent. My User class extends UserInterface meaning that methods like getRoles must be implemented on the User class, but in the new requisites they arent Assigned to the User.
What do you think it would be the best model for my needs?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I'm also trying something like this, but didn't manage to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Organization {
    private $id;
    private $name;
}

class User {
    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $password;
}

class UserOrganizationRelation {
    private $id;
    private $userId;
    private $organizationId;
    private $roles;
    private $isActive;
    private $level;
}
```